# Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rosserial-arduino

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I keep on getting, "Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rosserial-arduino" in the terminal. I even replaced indigo in that line of code with my current version of ROS, Melodic, and it still didn't work. Does anyone have a solution to this? I installed ROS correctly, I think.﻿ Does anyone know what to do?

I am doing a research project using ROS and an arduino uno and need to be able to install rosserial in order to connect the two and begin what I was doing. If anyone has a quick solution/workaround, it would be much appreciated.

Just some extra information to help diagnose the issue: I am running Ubuntu Linux 18.04 on an Oracle Virtual Machine. Also, as stated above, I installed the most recent version of ROS, that being Melodic.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295295/unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-rosserial-arduino/) by [johnwsmithv](https://answers.ros.org/users/36092/johnwsmithv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q294403, but replace `rosbridge-suite` with `rosserial`.

Summarising: `rosserial` (all of it) has not yet been released into ROS Melodic (see [status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=rosserial](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=rosserial)).

> If anyone has a quick solution/workaround, it would be much appreciated.

You could try to build the package from source. See #q252478 for the general workflow (but of course replace `indigo`/`kinetic` with `melodic`, and use the correct repositories).

---

Edit:

> Yeah I literally cannot install previous versions of ROS.. it is still giving me the same error that the rosserial package is giving me... smh... this is too annoying.

You may have missed it, but the fact that you cannot install any older versions of ROS on Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) is actually shown to you. See the [kinetic/Installation](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation) page fi:

[image: supported platforms for kinetic]

A similar table is shown on the Indigo installation page.

The more extensive version of that can be found in `REP-3: Target Platforms`: [here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021) for Kinetic, and [here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023) for Melodic.

Finally, with this:

> but of course replace `indigo`/`kinetic` with `melodic`, and use the correct repositories

I did not imply that you should uninstall ROS Melodic, but that anywhere in #q252478 it mentioned `indigo` or `kinetic`, you should put `melodic`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [johnwsmithv](https://answers.ros.org/users/36092/johnwsmithv/) on 2018-06-25**:
I'll try and build the package from the source. I did uninstall melodic, and I tried installing Indigo and Kinetic and it gave me the same error that rosserial is giving me.. smh. By the way thanks for the fast response. I'll update you on how it goes.

**Comment by [johnwsmithv](https://answers.ros.org/users/36092/johnwsmithv/) on 2018-06-25**:
Yeah I literally cannot install previous versions of ROS.. it is still giving me the same error that the rosserial package is giving me... smh... this is too annoying.

**Comment by [johnwsmithv](https://answers.ros.org/users/36092/johnwsmithv/) on 2018-06-26**:
I made it easy on myself and installed Ubuntu 16.04 and installed ROS-Kinetic from there and then rosserial. Thanks so much for your help... Hopefully they release a version of rosserial for Melodic eventually.